# How to draw a barplot?

Tags: r

I need to build a bar plot that will show the number of entities ("name") that visited guard1, guard2, and guard 3 in the resource column.
[image]

Comment: That sounds like a bar plot, not a histogram. What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data - post sample data as copy/pasteable code. Something like `dput(your_data[1:20, c("name", "resource")])` is a nice way to share a copy/pasteable sample of your data, including all class and structure information.

Comment: im trying to count the number of instances of guard I (i=1,2,3). than build a histogram that shows which guard handled more costumers

Comment: Are you familiar with `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution. Please note that the first part where I build an example for your data should be in your question, to help us answer. Providing what you tried is also a good start.

```
# here is a random copy from your data.frame format
df <- data.frame(name = sample(c(paste0("car", 1:8)), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 resource = sample(c("guard1", "guard2", "guard3", "electronicSeller"),
                                   20, replace = TRUE))

# Extract unique names for table with only rows for one guard number
g1 <- unique( df$name[ df$resource == "guard1" ] )
g2 <- unique( df$name[ df$resource == "guard2" ] )
g3 <- unique( df$name[ df$resource == "guard3" ] )

# barplot the length of each vector. 
barplot( c(length(g1), length(g2), length(g3) ), 
        names.arg = c("guard1", "guard2", "guard3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a barplot and the solution answered by @Gowachin is the best for you.

In case you will need and histogram, might check the distribution of your data I use the code below:

```
hist(df$variable, 
     main="Title", 
     xlab="unit on x axis", 
     border="black", 
     col="lightskyblue1",
     xlim=c(min(df$variable),max(df$variable)),
     las=1, 
     breaks=35)
```